# Upload external image url after compression to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the WriteStream Class to upload an image (external url) to my Google Cloud Storage Bucket.
It's working.
But I would like to compress it before it's being uploaded to the Bucket and when I try to use the built in imagejpg PHP compressor its failing. Like the stream doesn't accept it.

Can anyone point out what Im doing wrong?

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\WriteStream;


function upload_object_stream($bucketName, $objectName, $contents)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient([
        'keyFilePath' => 'gckey.json',
    ]);

    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);

    $writeStream = new WriteStream(null, [
        'chunkSize' => 1024 * 256, // 256KB
    ]);

    $uploader = $bucket->getStreamableUploader($writeStream, [
        'name' => $objectName,
    ]);

    $writeStream->setUploader($uploader);
    $stream = fopen($contents, 'r');

    while (($line = stream_get_line($stream, 1024 * 256)) !== false) {
        $writeStream->write($line);
    }
    $writeStream->close();
}



$image_name = 'https://vi.cdn.pxr.nl/.imaging/mte/vinl-website-theme/1152/dam/articles/2024/01/30/copyright-proshots-23140581.jpg/jcr:content/copyright-proshots-23140581.jpg';




$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_name); // For JPEG
ob_start();

imagejpeg($image, null, 10);
$img = ob_get_clean();

ob_end_clean();



upload_object_stream('stackpath-cdn-creatives-production', 'voetballer.jpg', $imageUrl); // url direct does work
//upload_object_stream('stackpath-cdn-creatives-production', 'voetballer.jpg', $img); // compressed image
```

I was expecting the imagejpg to work.
I prefer not to write the image to a temp folder to the server first.

Comment: You mention "it is failing". Provide more details as that is not a good problem description.